# Alexa M-search not received by Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit, upnp

I am using fauxmo to have Alexa trigger a script on a Raspberry Pi, which then triggers a BroadLink RM hub to send out IR and RF signals for my home theatre.

This has worked beautifully for a year or two, and yesterday it stopped. I did not touch anything, I swear!

I found out that fauxmo does no longer receive Alexa discovery requests.

When I ask Alexa (voice/web/app) to discover devices, it sends out SSDP M-SEARCH requests to 239.255.255.250 1900. I can verify this using Wireshark on a Windows laptop.

However, these requests do not seem to get to the Raspberry Pi anymore. I have tried with two Raspberries. Confirmed they are on they same WiFi network, which is Google Wifi (and confirmed Upnp is enabled). And I powercycled Alexa and Google Wifi.

I also sent M-SEARCH requests locally on the Raspberry Pi, and those are received.

window 1:

```
sudo tcpdump -n udp dst port 1900 -A
```

window 2 (on same Pi):

```
echo -e "M-SEARCH\r\nurn:Belkin:device:**" | nc.traditional -q 1 -u 239.255.255.250 1900
```

window 1 result:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:06:41.485902 IP 192.168.86.247.45796 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 31
E..;+.@...FO..V........l.'m.M-SEARCH
urn:Belkin:device:**
```

However, if I do this on 2 Pi's (window 1 on one, window 2 on the other), the request is not received. Actually, I also tried with another Ubuntu machine, so it's not specific to Pi.

I thought that it could be a general network issue, but then I would not see the Alexa requests on my Windows laptop.

I am at a loss - I did not make any code or configuration changes (actually it worked at the beginning of a movie "Alexa turn projector on", and it did not work after the end of the movie "Alexa turn projector off").

Comment: I just saw this... https://support.google.com/wifi/thread/11386387?hl=en...   but the two PI's both connect on 2.4GHz, so that can't be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Wiring the Pi to the Google WiFi pod worked, I posted this at Google WiFi instead - https://support.google.com/wifi/thread/13904262